# Datagrid - Dataset/Datatable binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, dataset

I have a Dataset formed with 4 Datatables and want to bind it to my datagrid but when I look at the datagrid it is empty.
So what I do is:

```
 DataSet dtsResults = myPcd.GetDimensionsDataSet();
 dtgResults.DataContext = dtsResults.Tables;
```

[image]

---ADD---
Here is how i form the Dataset:

```
    obcPcdlrnDimensionCommands.Clear();
    int maxNumCommands = (pcdPartProgram.Commands.Count < MAX_NUM_COMMANDS) ? pcdPartProgram.Commands.Count : MAX_NUM_COMMANDS;
    PCDLRN.Commands pcdCommands = pcdPartProgram.Commands;
    //2. ciclo su tutti i comandi
    int numTables = dtsDimensions.Tables.Count + 1;
    dtsDimensions.Tables.Add("DATA_TABLE_" + numTables);
    dtsDimensions.Tables[0].Columns.Add();
    dtsDimensions.Tables[0].Columns.Add();
    dtsDimensions.Tables[0].Columns.Add();
    dtsDimensions.Tables[0].Columns.Add();
    String CurName = string.Empty;
    for (int iCommand = 1; iCommand < maxNumCommands; iCommand++)
    {
      PCDLRN.Command pcdCommand = pcdCommands.Item(iCommand);
      if (pcdCommand.IsDimension && pcdCommand.Marked)
      {
        if (pcdCommand.Type == PCDLRN.OBTYPE.DIMENSION_START_LOCATION || pcdCommand.Type == PCDLRN.OBTYPE.DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION)
        {
          CurName = pcdCommand.ID;
        }
        else
        {
          if (pcdCommand.ID != string.Empty)
            CurName = pcdCommand.ID;

          double approxMeasured = Math.Round(pcdCommand.DimensionCommand.Measured, 9);
          dtsDimensions.Tables[0].Rows.Add(CurName, delenda_PART_NAME, pcdCommand.DimensionCommand.AxisLetter, approxMeasured);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Click at one of those loupes and tell us if the table is empty. Also, don't post screenshots but actual code. Shall we use photoshop to see the code under the debugger window?

Comment: where is your datagrid binding code,,,

Comment: @KuttyRajeshValangai Sorry didn't make it clear. dtgResults is my datagrid. Isn't dtgResults.DataContext = dtsResults.Tables;  the binding code?

Comment: @TimSchmelter please see my ADD

Comment: what do you mean by this `want to bind it to my datagrid`

Comment: @safi I want my datagrid to show the data in the Dataset

Comment: @Patrick i added an answer look at it and tell me if that is working with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid in WPF shows only one table and you tell her to bind to DataSet which is more than one table, because of that you have two options:
1- bind one table to ItemsSource like this:

```
yourDatagrid.ItemsSource = yourDataSet.Tables[0]; \\or yourDataSet.Tables["TableName"]
```

2- bind all the dataSet and then tell you datagrid to bind your specific table like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableName}"/>
```